# how to print invalid characters using DB2 SQL Query

Tags: sql, db2

I have a XML column in my db2 table, some XML's having invalid characters.

how to print invalid characters using DB2 SQL Query

Error : Invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x2)

XML having non ascii characters

Comment: Which Db2 version and OS platform? What is the codepage for printing? What does "invalid" character mean? Non-printable in your codepage or a wrong character that should not have been inserted?

Comment: Please, edit your question with some example of XML column value with invalid characters and the result desired.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.